# can't pass multible table in view

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a logo on the certain portion. as shown in the attachment. also attaching the codes

**controller:**

```
$recentJobs = DB::table('jobs')
    ->select('jobs.*','categories.id as cid','company_logo as cicon')
    ->join('categories','jobs.job_cat_id','=','categories.id')
    ->where('application_deadline', '>=', $current_time)
    ->where('publication_status', '1')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/','FrontendController@index2');
Route::get('/test-theme','FrontendController@index3');
Route::get('/job-categories','FrontendController@allJobCategories');
Route::get('/company-jobs/{id}','FrontendController@companyJobs');
Route::get('/jobs-location/{id}','FrontendController@JobLoc');
```

**view**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    {{-- @for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) --}}
    @foreach ($recentJobs as $item)
        @php
            $encrypted = $item->job_id;
        @endphp
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-12 m-0 p-0">
                <div class="section3_job_div">
                    <div class="section3_job_image_div">
                        @if($item->company_logo!='')
                            <img src="{{URL::asset('uploads/companyLogo/'.$item->company_logo) }}" class="section3_hotjob_image" alt="company logo"/>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

It's showing data from "jobs" table i want to show logo from companies table
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xndEA.png)

[CompaniesTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWgMS.png)

[jobs Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xndEA.png)

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Seems that you are selecting the logo as `cicon` instead of `company_logo`. Also, how are you returning the controller data into the view?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong field for company_logo.its alias is "cicon". Try below code to replace image tag with condition.
@if($item->cicon!='')
cicon) }}" class="section3_hotjob_image" alt="company logo"/>
@endif